# How should I go about covering an entire room in black material?

Tags: walls, cover

I have a birthday party coming up where I need to cover an entire room in black material of some kind (theme is "1970s in Space" and we're sticking glow in the dark stars on this material). The walls are quite short, maybe 8 - 10 feet

What is the best/cheapest material to do this, and how would I go about sticking it up? (I was thinking of [Blu-Tack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blu-Tack).)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

4 feet wide and 200 feet long roll of black paper for less than $25: [http://www.amazon.com/Spectra-ArtKraft-Duo-Finish-PAC67304-Pacon/dp/B00006IE1U](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00006IE1U)

I would use painter's masking tape (the kind that peels back off without peeling the paint off the walls and does not leave a sticky residue) and make little rolled tubes of the tape to stick the paper to walls and ceiling, so the tape does not show.

Comment: If the theme is "70's in Space" you better have a glow-in-the-dark Starship Enterprise.

Comment: This is a lot cheaper than my would-be suggestion of 4x8' black foam board, which is upwards of $50 a sheet.

Comment: Thanks very much! That's a great deal, but I couldn't find the equivalent on UK Amazon (or somewhere that would ship here cheaply). For anyone that stumbles upon this question, the closest I could get was http://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B00X5LC6UI/ref=pe_385721_37986871_TE_item. It's plastic though, so weight and texture are different to paper.